# pandas_profiling taking way too long to run

Tags: pandas, pandas-profiling

If anyone experimented with [pandas-profiling package](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling), help me with any insights you might have with making it run faster. The output report from the package is very neat and detailed, but creating the report takes way too long even with moderate sized dataset. About 10 columns and 400K rows from Kaggle bulldozers dataset took 21 min (non-gpu). Wondering if its worth investigating further.

```
df.shape
(401125, 9)


start = datetime.datetime.now()
profile = df.profile_report(title="Exploring Dataset")
profile.to_file(output_file=Path("./data_report.html"))

end = datetime.datetime.now()
print(end-start)

0:21:23.976324
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you are interested in, you can disable other functionalities of pandas-profiling that consume most time, because it is modular. This is currently your go-to solution in speeding up, together with sampling your dataset.

There are several related issues here:

- https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/293
- https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/261
- https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/76
- https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/222

In the long run, we plan on allow for better parallelization and more sensible defaults:
https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/279

**Edit:**

Since v2.4 there is minimal mode, that configures the package to automatically use  lower-computational settings: https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling#large-datasets